# java validation without JDialog

Tags: java, swing, validation, element

without dialog message how to validate this one?

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
    null,
    "Mobile number can't be empty",
    "Error",
    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: what do you want to validate?

Comment: It should read "Mobile number can't be empty". Validation done.

Comment: @Waldheinz I guess you must be professor in English grammar :) but very nice comment :)

Comment: this message is showing in message box.i want to do this without messagebox.

Comment: @user741996 be more precise as to what exactly do you want. (-1) So far from what I see everybody is guessing what you want and you do not like the answers. Try to rewrite the question as I am sure it will be closed for not being actually a question if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

On the Console with `System.out.println("Your MEssage");`? Or on a `JLabel` on some JFrame?

Comment: no no if we use this one it will be print in netbeans.

Comment: The what do you want? Do you want to have the Message Box without the Box?

Comment: Please be more specific on what "without box" means.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
    JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane( "Mobile number can't be empty", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog( "Error" );
    Container contentPane = dialog.getContentPane();

    myPanelWherever.add(contentPane);
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though I think you should rewrite the question I will try to answer.

I am quessing that you should be asking how to let a user know that he entered an invalid input into a textfield, as probably that is where the phone number is.

Why don't you then highlight either the background of the text field to red `tf.setBackground(Color.RED)` or its border                 `tf.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.PINK, 5))` ?

This way you do not need to show the dialog, and user knows something is wrong in this field.

Comment: no no this is not a way.

Comment: else if(txtMobile.getText().isEmpty())
           areaResult.setText("mobile number can't be empty");

Comment: @user741996 I do not understand so you got it sorted now using another TextField? But this is pretty much what @Lukas Knuth suggested first in his answer just using the JLabel which is more appropriate for this case.

Comment: best of BreakDance in this thread +1 for everyone

Answer (score 1):

> I want to do this without message box.

[`InputVerifier`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html) may be suitable in this context.